the spectrum of a sentence in a signature with only equality sign
The spectrum of a first-order sentence $\phi$ is the set of all such natural numbers $n > 0$ that $\phi$ is feasible in some normal model with cardinality equals to $n$.
Assume $\psi$ is a sentence that contains only equality sign, quantifiers and boolean connectives, i. e. signature consists only of equlaity sign. Show that either spectrum of $\psi$ is finite or spectrum is co-finite.
I found out that if $\psi$ is feasible in the finite model $M$, that $|M|=n$, then $\psi$ also feasible in any model $M'$ with same cardinality, since any bijection respect equality. Then i tried to prove by contradiction and stuck. Can someone help me a hint any approch to the problem?

Do you know the compactness theorem?

@ZhenLin Yes, i know this one, and know that if a sentence $\phi$ has models of arbitrarily large finite cardinality, we can use this theorem to show $\phi$ must also have infinite models.

Suppose for contradiction that that spectrum of $\psi$ is infinite and coinfinite. Then there are abitrarily large finite models of $\psi$ and arbitrarily large finite models of $\lnot \psi$.
By compactness (or by taking an ultraproduct), both $\psi$ and $\lnot \psi$ have infinite models, and by Löwenheim-Skolem, both have countably infinite models.
But any two countably infinite structures in the language of equality are isomorphic (any bijection between them is an isomorphism), contradiction.

For each $n$, add a $0$-ary predicate "there exist at least $n$ distinct elements".
Then you can check directly that we have quantifier elimination (in the pure theory of equality + natural interpretation of these predicates).
It follows that any sentence is equivalent to a Boolean combination of these predicates, which yields the proposition.
